# Prevent zero values from being selected. Ignore zero values (totals)

Tags: php, mysql, operators, expression

I want the program to ignore zero totals. I'm trying to stop auto awards to non-participants with zero totals. I added the >= expression after the && operators. Is this correct for kills and networth?

```
    $fetch_nor_killers = mysql_query("SELECT wk,bk,hk,dk,pk,mk, code, p, (wk+bk+hk+dk+pk+mk) as totalKills FROM r$round[round]_p WHERE status = '". normal ."' ORDER BY totalKills DESC LIMIT 3");
    $killa_rank = 0;

    while($killa = mysql_fetch_array($fetch_nor_killers))
    {
        $killa_rank++;

        if($killa_rank == 1 && $killa['totalKills'] >= 1)
        {
            $killa_award = "freeopkiller1";
        }
        else
        if($killa_rank == 2 && $killa['totalKills'] >= 1)
        {
            $killa_award = "freeopkiller2";
        }
        else
        if($killa_rank == 3 && $killa['totalKills'] >= 1)
        {
            $killa_award = "freeopkiller3";
        }
```

Same thing here with networth. Just trying to avoid awarding a inactivate user. @Jagrut

```
        $fetch_top_subs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM r$round[round]_p WHERE subscription != '". none ."' ORDER BY  networth DESC LIMIT 3");
     $sub_rank = 0;

     while($sub = mysql_fetch_array($fetch_top_subs))
    {
         $sub_rank++;

        if($sub_rank == 1 && $sub_rank['networth'] >= 1)
        {
         $sub_award = "first_sub";
        }
        else
        if($sub_rank == 2 && $sub_rank['networth'] >= 1)
        {
         $sub_award = "second_sub";
        }
```

About to test these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, i would like you to be more clear with the question. But from what i have understood, this can be the problem with your code:

You are using the `$totalKills` directly. You can either assign it to a variable and then use it or you need to use `$killa` for accessing `$totalKills`, i.e.

Use it as:

```
$anyVar = $killa['totalKills'];
```

and then use `$anyVar` for your operations or directly use `$killa['totalKills']` in place of `$totalKills`.

Hope this helped.

Comment: This points me in the right direction and  helped me realize how to test it.Block is lifted.

Comment: Your answer to this question#2, answered a question#1 I deleted over a month ago as well. Helped a lot.